# How would one go about unit testing javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

What is the recommended way of unit testing javascript and jQuery?

- What frameworks?
- Does the framework
  integrate with build tools? (CI,
  maven and such)

Please share your experiences in this field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Unit-testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809/javascript-unit-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this: jQuery QUnit

[jQuery unit testing library](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)

[Samples for QUnit](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/jquery/test/unit/)

[Manual to start](http://www.swift-lizard.com/2009/11/24/test-driven-development-with-jquery-qunit/)

[Maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/qunit-maven-plugin/)

Also, can check this solution (found in my bookmarks): [js-test-driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/)

Comment: is it possible to do things like mocking ajax calls?

Comment: yes, read about stop() and start() functions

Answer (score 1):

You might have heard of [JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit). That's what I've used in the past.

Comment: JSUnit is no longer maintained, please consider Mocha, Jasmine or QUnit instead